# invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(int)' on a null object reference in Android

Tags: android

I'm implementing the task of record the voice and save in external storage file.The voice is recording and stop the record this two functions are work only on one button click event.but the problem is when i click on button first time for recording the voice , then in-between recording again i click on button it will stop the record , again click on button application is crashed and getting NullPointerException. Can someone help me how to proper work with recording audio and stop recording on the same button. Thanks !!

Here is my Button click event code.

```
imageRecord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_Record);
    imageRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickCount += 1;
            Log.e("clickCount ", " click !!! " + clickCount);
            if (clickCount == 1) {

                if (vesselId == null) {

                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
                    newAudioFile = 0 + "_" + s.format(new Date()) + ".mp3";
                    Log.e(" newAudioFile ", " = " + newAudioFile);
                    outputFile = baseDir + "/classnkk_audio/" + newAudioFile;
                    Log.e("outputFile ", " = " + outputFile);

                    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

                    imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record);
                    try {
                        myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                        myAudioRecorder.start();
                        myChronometer.start();

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else if (vesselId != null)
                {
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
                    newAudioFile = vesselId + "_" + s.format(new Date()) + ".mp3";
                    Log.e(" newAudioFile ", " = " + newAudioFile);
                    outputFile = baseDir + "/classnkk_audio/" + newAudioFile;
                    Log.e("outputFile ", " = " + outputFile);

                    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
                    imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record);
                    try {
                        myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                        myAudioRecorder.start();
                        myChronometer.start();

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } else if (clickCount == 2) {
                imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_pause);
                myAudioRecorder.stop();
                myAudioRecorder.reset();
                myAudioRecorder.release();
                myAudioRecorder = null;
                myChronometer.stop();
                long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - myChronometer.getBase();
                String strTime  = String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) elapsedMillis),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) elapsedMillis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds
                                (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) elapsedMillis)));

                Log.e("elapsedMillis ", " of myChronometer !!! " + strTime);


            }

            if (clickCount == 2) {
                imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record);
                clickCount = 0;
                myAudioRecorder = null;
                myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                Log.e("(clickCount == 3 ) ", " click !!! " + clickCount);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: error clearly states that your mediarecorder object is null, try to debug your code why it is null

Comment: Yes this is the error of java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: where you initialize your mediarecorder object?

Comment: Means `myAudioRecorder ` is `null` add null check and initialize it if null when `vesselId == null` or  `vesselId != null`

Comment: but i cant see any initialization of myAudioRecoder object in your code

Comment: I initialize    myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer); before imageRecord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_Record);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing null into `clickCount == 2` block

```
} else if (clickCount == 2) {
                ...
                myAudioRecorder = null;
```

But you never initialized into first if block. So add initialization block into first if block.

---

Initialize `myAudioRecorder` like below code

```
if (clickCount == 1) {
        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder(); // <<< Initialize here
                if (vesselId == null) {
```

Comment: I can't understand . What you saying.

Comment: I am saying that you should initialise `myAudioRecorder` into 'if (clickCount == 1) {' block. Am I clear now? See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In line no 84 you are making `myAudioRecorder = null;`. Thatswhy it is throwing the exception.Initilize it again inside the `if (clickCount == 1)` block